# Why don't snails run out of slime?

Tags: locomotion, snail

I understand that land-snail-slime and slug-slime are made of mucus.

> Externally, one kind of mucus is produced by the foot of the gastropod
> and is usually used for crawling on.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snail_slime

Travelling on a trail of mucus seems very expensive. How do snails manage to replace it so abundantly without ever running out? Do they ever run out - if so, what happens to them?

Comment: Cool info here: https://www.google.com/search?q=mucus+slug+dry+weight&oq=mucus+slug+dry+weight

Comment: Why don't you run out of mucus when you have a bad cold?

Comment: @jamesqf  If a human produced mucus in the same proportion to body size as a snail, they would dry out within minutes. Also a lot of mucus from a cold gets swallowed and so is recycled.